# Does emmet in atom not work with jade?

Tags: pug, atom-editor, emmet

Well today is becoming a pain in the rear. I have a problem & stack overflow has a problem with my problem. I am trying to figure out why emmet is not working with jade. I tried posting the question but stack doesn't think it qualifies.

So I have to use an image to explain what is wrong. Here is a picture of my problem.

[image]
[My Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSoUn.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default Jade will render `.anything` to `<div class='anything'></div>`. So you don't have to specify `div` element in front of the class name.

Comment: Yeah I typed div.box and it just deleted the div part. Same with h1's and so on